# Is it possible to weave into every method of a project using MethodDecorator.Fody?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xamarin.forms, fody, compile-time-weaving

I understand [MethodDecorator.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/MethodDecorator) provides a means to define an attribute decorator that can be used on any method throughout the assembly. Is it possible to have it automatically apply to all methods within that assembly? (E.g. as if I decorated every method with that attribute.) Or is there any other Fody extension that can allow me to do this?

I'm using **C#** / **.NET** in a **Xamrin.Forms** project.

If it's not possible in Fody, is there any way to automate it in PostSharp or another framework?

Comment: Try to use [MethodBoundaryAspect](https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov In their documentation it shows the usage of an attribute decorator `[TransactionScope]`. Is there a way to use it without having to manually add the attribute decorators to each method?